# How to pass a variable in url in fromJSON command

Tags: json, r, rjson, rjsonio, jsonlite

I am trying to pass a variable in the url and flatten using jsonlite, but i am not able to pass variable pages using the loop. How do i loop using FromJSON?

```
pages<- list()
for(i in 1:20) {
mydata <- fromJSON("https:www.example.com/page="+i+"&access_token=xyz", flatten = TRUE) 
}
filings <-rbind.pages(pages)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
pages<- list()
for(i in 1:20) {
  mydata <- fromJSON(paste("https:www.example.com/page=", i, "&access_token=xyz", sep = "+"), flatten = TRUE)
}
filings <-rbind.pages(pages)
```

Comment: you are missing the flatten=TRUE which is quite important for the nested json objects.

Comment: Answer modified, copy it simply to the end of fromJSON function.

Comment: it is only giving 1 page information after i do the rbind.

Comment: The for loop work correctly. The mistake is in the last line of your code. Try something like rbind(mydata) or provide reproducible data.

Comment: yes it was able to retrieve the pages but it is not rbinding them.